# Scraping a domain for links recursively using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is the code I'm using for scraping all the urls of a domain:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor

class UrlsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'urlsspider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://example.com/']

    rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), unique=True), callback='parse', follow=True))

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in LxmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=self.allowed_domains, unique=True).extract_links(response):
            print link.url

            yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse)
```

As you can see that I've used `unique=True` but it's still printing duplicate urls in the terminal whereas I want only the unique urls and not duplicate urls.

Any help on this matter will be very helpful.

Comment: Scrapy, by default, uses `scrapy.dupefilters.RFPDupeFilter` to detect and filter duplicate requests. That said, you may see a URL multiple times in logging output but those will only be hit once (unless you set `dont_filter` to True). I'd suggest creating a `Link` item and use a Pipeline like this one: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html?highlight=item%20duplicate#duplicates-filter

Answer (score 0):

Since the code looks at the content of the URLs recursively, you will see the duplicate URLs from the parsing of other pages. You essentially have multiple instances of LxmlLinkExtractor().